# How to handle grails exceptions in an ajax request?

Tags: grails, groovy, error-handling

If I am making a regular request I can define handling of errors and exceptions in UrlMappings.groovy as in the following example:

```
    "403"(controller: 'error', action: 'index', params:['code':'403'])
    "404"(controller: 'error', action: 'index', params:['code':'404'])
    "500"(controller: 'error', action: 'index', params:['code':'500'])
    "500"(controller: 'home', action: 'noPrivileges', exception: IllegalOperationException)
```

I can then handle the errors in a specific controller and render a view of my choice e.g.

```
class ErrorController {

    def index = {
        render view: "/errors/myErrorPage", model: [code: params.code]
    }
}
```

This works perfectly and whenever there is an error on server I get my error page.

Now how can I achieve the very same behavior for ajax requests? I am making ajax requests either with grails [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) or [formRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html). Everytime when an exception occurs on the server, I want to execute the same piece of code in javascript (e.g. I want to show an alert with alert('There was an exception')).

The above described approach does not work for ajax requests. I still get back an error and even though there is content of myErrorPage.gsp in the error, it is not printed into the html element which I specified with update parameter of formRemote or remoteFunction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a perfectly clean solution compatible with the approach which is used for handling standard requests.

You need to modify action which is handling the error as in the following example:

```
class ErrorController {

    def index = {
        if (request.xhr) {
             response.status = 200
             render template: "/errors/myAjaxErrorTemplate", model: [code: params.code]
        } else {
             render view: "/errors/myErrorPage", model: [code: params.code]
        }
    }
}
```

With request.xhr you can differentiate between ajax request and a standard request. In ajax request you further need to tell grails that the response is OK with setting response status to 200.

Very nice and clean. :) I am surprised this can't be googled anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

The `remoteFunction` trigger a couple of events `onFailure` and `on_ERROR_CODE`. You can use that events to show your warning messages.

You can see more details in [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I was asking. This way I have to modify each formRemote and remoteFunction in my code. But that is not the worst drawback of this approach. It also does not allow me to act differently depending on the type of exception thrown from the server. Any idea how could I achieve this?

Comment: Yes you can, on_ERROR_CODE is a event where you substitute _ERROR_CODE by your error, e.g. on500(alert('That was a big error')), on404(alert('Error 404')), etc. You can create a javascript function and pass the code on500(myFunction('500')) on404(myFunction('404')). Maybe you could to use jQuery to inject that code.

Comment: Yes but I want to display a message based on the type of exception not type of error code. All my exceptions have the same error code 500.

Comment: You need check the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ there are a `error` parameter which is a function with three arguments, third argument is errorThrow. I'm not jQuery expert but I guess you can find your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If the request status is set correctly you could define an JavaScript function via the `onFailure` attribute of `remoteFunction`/`formRemote`.

Within this function you could handle your exception on client side.

Using the sample from the docs it could look like this:

```
<select onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'bookByName',
                       update: [success: 'great', failure: 'ohno'],
                       params: '\'bookName=\' + this.value'),
                       onFailure: 'handleError'}">
    <option>first</option>
    <option>second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I was asking. This way I have to modify each formRemote and remoteFunction in my code. But that is not the worst drawback of this approach. It also does not allow me to act differently depending on the type of exception thrown from the server. Any idea how could I achieve this?

Comment: Within you JavaScript function `handleError` you can access the `status` of your response like this `function handleError(response) {alert(reponse.status)}` - so you can handle each status individually ...